# Error "does not contain valid backup metadata" when trying to CREATE TABLE in BigQuery from Firestore Backup

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

I've created data base via Google Firestore and I'm trying to display it in BigQuery. First I export a backup to Storage Bucket via Google Shell (according to documentation). Then I enter BigQuery and when I try to Create table I always get an error. Here is what your documentation says:
Verify [KIND_COLLECTION_ID] is specified in your Cloud Storage URI. If you specify the URI without [KIND_COLLECTION_ID], you receive the following error: does not contain valid backup metadata. (error code: invalid).

I've tried every file in my Bucket and I always get errors like:
gs://olimp-data/2019-03-28T11:39:33_12594/2019-03-28T11:39:33_12594.overall_export_metadata does not contain valid backup metadata.

or

Entity was of unexpected kind "olimp".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore) says:

> Note: Do not use the file ending in overall_export_metadata. This file
>   is not usable by BigQuery.

Please use other file:

The URI for your Cloud Firestore export file should end with `[KIND_COLLECTION_ID].export_metadata`. For example: `default_namespace_kind_Book.export_metadata`. In this example, Book is the collection ID, and `default_namespace_kind_Book` is the file name generated by Cloud Firestore.

and export specific collections as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data

Comment: I read it and i don't understand.. Could you please explain it on my example?
I have these files on my Storage:
2019-03-28T08:34:00_20786.overall_export_metadata
all_namespaces/all_kinds/all_namespaces_all_kinds.export_metadata
all_namespaces/all_kinds/output-0

What should i do?

Comment: you need to export specific collections see the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data